# But I would say that, wouldn’t I?

Tags: phrases

What does it mean when after a personal statement someone says "But I would say that, wouldn’t I?"?  Does it mean "any way, it is my idea"?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. I came across such a sentence in one of the stories in a Cambridge English Readers. I find it difficult to decide whether 'I would say' is a conditional of 'say' – I do not think so – or a past simple of the modal auxiliary 'will' followed by the bare infinitive of 'say' – which I think it is. However, using a past for a present situation makes sense when the situation is hypothetical, which is not the case here. Why not use 'I will say'?

Comment: Or it might be a conditional, after all! Meaning something like 'If you asked for my opinion, I would say that…', where the if-clause is understood...

Answer (score 3):

It means something like: but *of course* I would say that. It implies that there's some reason what the speaker is saying is typically or obviously biased from their position.

It's a kind of [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), which gives it kind of an *"I know you know what I mean"* tone.

Here's a quote from an [interview](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fk1HMjyzPh8C&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22I+would+say+that+wouldn%27t+I%22&source=bl&ots=qrgQCCLcVN&sig=0nptDfaSy-EvzoKI33DIPa4M3bw&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBmoVChMI6Jbcr87NxwIVS5WACh0ZNQGz#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20say%20that%20wouldn%27t%20I%22&f=false) with Nick Clegg:

> **Part of the challenge for a third party in this country, it seems to me, is that you have no prospsect of winning power for a long time to come. But once you admit that, the media will say there's no point in voting for you.**
>
> I think you're being unduly pessimistic. Well, I would say that, wouldn't I? [...]

Of *course* Clegg would call that point of view pessimistic -- otherwise he wouldn't be undertaking the challenge himself! He's hinting, *"I have bias here, I'm not a neutral party to ask about this."*

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a bit of context:
Joan and Lisa are friends. Joan has a tendency to talk before she thinks, and can be somewhat of a pessimist at times. Lisa has a crush on Paul.

Lisa asks: "Do you think he thinks of me?"
Joan answers: "Nah, he's probably hanging with that girl from the bar"
Joan sees Lisa is sad by what she suggests, and so adds: "But I would say that, wouldn't I?"

The sentence means "I am prone to say stuff like that, so take it with a grain of salt." or if you will "Just because I say it a lot, doesn't make it right"

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that this rejoinder comes from

> He would say that, wouldn't he?"

which had its first entry in the Oxford Dictionary of Quotations in 1979. (When I Google for "I would say that..." it's this version above which comes up at the top of the list, along with *MRDA*)

This famous phrase is a misquotation of an answer given by Mandy Rice-Davies during the Stephen Ward trial in 1963.

> When James Burge, the defence counsel, pointed out that Lord Astor
>   denied an affair or having even met her, she replied, "Well (giggle)
>   he would, wouldn’t he?"[11] (often misquoted "Well he would say that,
>   wouldn't he?") - *Wikipedia, below*.

There was great national interest in this trial (part of the "Profumo Affair" which powerfully undermined the Conservative government of Harold Macmillan).

You can read about Mandy Rice-Davies *[here at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandy_Rice-Davies)*, where there's also the above reference to the famous rhetorical question (MRDA), as well as a brief summary of the Profumo Affair and the Stephen Ward trial. The whole thing caused a massive crack in the class assumptions of Britain in the early sixties, and it opened the way for a more progressive (and "swinging") time, as well as discontent at the injustices of the "establishment".